# How can I edit the WooCommerce Memberships "set end date" function if it has no filter to hook into the function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

In the WooCommerce Memberships plugin file class-wc-memberships-user-membership.php I am trying to edit this function in my theme's functions.php file so I don't have to edit this file directly:

```
    /**
     * Sets the membership end datetime.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @param string|int $date end date either as a unix timestamp or mysql datetime string - defaults to empty string (unlimited membership, no end date)
     * @return bool success
     */
    public function set_end_date( $date = '' ) {

        $end_timestamp = '';
        $end_date      = '';

        if ( is_numeric( $date ) ) {
            $end_timestamp = (int) $date;
        } elseif ( is_string( $date ) ) {
            $end_timestamp = strtotime( $date );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $end_timestamp ) ) {

            $plan = $this->get_plan();

            // if the plan is with fixed dates, ensure the end date is set at midnight of the end day
            if ( $plan && $plan->is_access_length_type( 'fixed' )  ) {

                try {

                    $utc_timezone   = new \DateTimeZone( 'UTC' );
                    $local_timezone = new \DateTimeZone( wc_timezone_string() );
                    $end_datetime   = new \DateTime( date( 'c', $end_timestamp ), $utc_timezone );

                    // since the input date is in UTC, convert the date to local timezone, set to end of the day, then convert back to UTC for storage purposes
                    $end_datetime->setTimezone( $local_timezone );
                    $end_datetime->setTime( 0, 0 );
                    $end_datetime->setTimezone( $utc_timezone );

                    $end_timestamp = $end_datetime->getTimestamp();

                } catch ( \Exception $e ) {

                    // in case of DateTime errors, just use the end date timestamp as is but issue a warning
                    trigger_error( sprintf( 'Unable to end start date for User Membership #%d: %s', $this->get_id(), $e->getMessage() ), E_USER_WARNING );
                }
            }

            $end_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', (int) $end_timestamp );
        }

        // update end date in post meta
        $success = (bool) update_post_meta( $this->id, $this->end_date_meta, $end_date ?: '' );

        // set expiration scheduled events
        $this->schedule_expiration_events( $end_timestamp );

        return $success;
    }
```

However there is no filter I can use to hook into it. I just need to change the `$end_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', (int) $end_timestamp );` to `$end_date = date( 'Y-m-d 05:00:00', (int) $end_timestamp );` to force all the memberships to expire at midnight on the day they are due to expire.
Can someone assist me in accomplishing this so I don't have to edit this file directly?

Answer (score 1):

The only option here to update the end date meta without editing the file is the below hook.

```
    /**
     * Fires immediately after updating a post's metadata.
     *
     * @since 2.9.0
     *
     * @param int    $meta_id    ID of updated metadata entry.
     * @param int    $object_id  Post ID.
     * @param string $meta_key   Metadata key.
     * @param mixed  $meta_value Metadata value. This will be a PHP-serialized string representation of the value
     *                           if the value is an array, an object, or itself a PHP-serialized string.
     */
    do_action( 'updated_postmeta', $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
```

Here you can get the membership ID in the variable `$object_id` - you can check if it's a membership object in the add_action and updated the meta accordingly